# SPFx JQuery Dialog button click does not find public function

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx

I am new to TypeScript and Sharepoint SPFx development.  I have a jquery UI dialog box and a public function in the same class that makes some MSGRAPH calls after the button has been clicked. The button click returns with error `this.addAlert is not a function`.  I think the problem is that the dialog code executes outside the web part context and hence does not know about the function available in the webpart context.  How can I use the button click to run within the webpart context?

Here is the Dialog code.

```
    export default class YlsSpAlertWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IYlsSpAlertWebPartProps> {

      public constructor() {
        super();
        SPComponentLoader.loadCss('//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
      }

public render(): void {

    this.domElement.innerHTML = AlertTemplate.templateHtml;
    const dialogOptions: JQueryUI.DialogOptions = {
      width: "50%",
      height: "auto",
      buttons: {
        "Subscribe": function (e) {
          this.addAlert("Yes");
          jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "No Thanks": function (e) {
          console.log("moo");
          this.addAlert("No");
          jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Ask me later": function (e) {
          this.addAlert("Ask Me Later");
          jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    };

    jQuery('.dialog', this.domElement).dialog(dialogOptions);
    jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
  }


     public addAlert(status: string): void {
        var url = "/sites/" + this.context.pageContext.site.id + "/lists";
        var listId = "";
        var email = this.getCurrentUserEmail();
        var recordExists = false;
        let item: SubscriptionListItem;
        this.context.msGraphClientFactory
          .getClient()
          .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
            client
              .api(url)
              .top(1)
              .filter("equals=(displayName, 'Subscriptions'")
              .version("v1.0")
              .get((err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                  console.error(err);
                  return;
                }
                console.log(res);
                listId = res.id;
              });
          });

}
```

...skipping the rest of the boilerplate generated by the template

Comment: Where/how is addAlert defined? It looks like it's not on the same object 'this' refers to.

Comment: @Charlie it is defined in the same class that inherits from `BaseClientSideWebPart`.  
`this.addAlert("yes");`
works when not using it the dialog button click.

Comment: I suspect "this" is referring to the dialogOptions instance instead of the BaseClientSideWebPart

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var event=this.addAlert;
    const dialogOptions: JQueryUI.DialogOptions = {
      width: "50%",
      height: "auto",
      buttons: {
        "Subscribe": function (e) {
          event("Yes");
          //this.addAlert("Yes");
          jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "No Thanks": function (e) {
          console.log("moo");
          event("no");
          jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Ask me later": function (e) {
          //this.addAlert("Ask Me Later");
          jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: This did not work but helped me find the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked answered at [sharepoint spfx forum](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276286/spfx-jquery-dialog-button-click-does-not-find-public-function/276292?noredirect=1#comment293902_276292)

```
public onDialogButtonClick(status: string, e): void {
    this.addAlert(status);
    jQuery('.dialog', this.domElement).dialog("close");
}
public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = AlertTemplate.templateHtml;
    const dialogOptions: JQueryUI.DialogOptions = {
      width: "50%",
      height: "auto",
      buttons: {
        "Subscribe": this.onDialogButtonClick.bind(this, "Subscribe"),
        "No Thanks": this.onDialogButtonClick.bind(this, "No Thanks"),
        "Ask me later": this.onDialogButtonClick.bind(this, "Ask me later")
      }
    };

    jQuery('.dialog', this.domElement).dialog(dialogOptions);
    jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
}
```